# Im trying to make a an app that calculates the WPM

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Im trying to make a an app that calculates the WPM.  In the end of the game I would like to use a timer to stop the app after 60 seconds. I can't figure out how to stop it. I'm trying to stop it with conditional statement. But I don't know how to implement it with SwiftUI. If anyone had any other ideas that would be great.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var userInput = ""
    @State var modalview = false
    @State var getstarted = false
    @EnvironmentObject var timerHolder : TimerHolder
    var body: some View {

        ZStack() {
            modalView(modalview: $modalview, userInput: userInput)

        }.sheet(isPresented: $modalview) {

        modalView(modalview: self.$modalview)

        }

    }

}




        struct modalView : View {
         @ObservedObject var durationTimer = TimerHolder()

          @Binding var modalview : Bool
            @State var userInput: String = ""


              var body: some View {

                VStack{

                   Button(action: {
                      self.modalview = true
                                 }) {
                                    TextField("Get Started", text:$userInput)
                                        .background(Color.gray)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
//                                        .frame(width: 300, height: 250).cornerRadius(20)
                    }
                                    Text("\(userInput.count)")
                                    if durationTimer == 60 {
                                                .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
                                            Alert(title: Text("Reminder"), message: Text("You wrote"), primaryButton: .default(Text("Yes"), action: { self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() })
                                                , secondaryButton: .cancel(Text("No")))
                                        }; else {
                                                                            }




                  }
            }

        }

class TimerHolder : ObservableObject {
var timer : Timer!
@Published var count = 0
func start() {
    self.timer?.invalidate()
    self.count = 0
    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) {
        _ in
        self.count += 1
        print(self.count)
    }
}






struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed some codes to give you a clue.

```
      struct ContentView: View {
    @State var userInput = ""
    @State var modalview = false
    @State var getstarted = false
    @EnvironmentObject var timerHolder : TimerHolder
    var body: some View {

        ZStack() {
            modalView(modalview: $modalview, userInput: userInput)

        }.sheet(isPresented: $modalview) {

        modalView(modalview: self.$modalview)

        }

    }

}


        struct modalView : View {


         @ObservedObject var durationTimer = TimerHolder()

          @Binding var modalview : Bool
            @State var userInput: String = ""


              var body: some View {

                VStack{

                   Button(action: {
                      self.modalview = true
                                 }) {
                                    TextField("Get Started", text:$userInput)
                                        .background(Color.gray)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
//                                        .frame(width: 300, height: 250).cornerRadius(20)
                    }
                    Text("\(userInput.count)").alert(isPresented: self.$durationTimer.count) {
                                            Alert(title: Text("Reminder"),
                                                  message: Text("You wrote"),
                                                  primaryButton: .default(Text("Yes"), action: { self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                                                print(123)
                                            })
                                                ,
                                                  secondaryButton: .cancel(Text("No")))
                    }




                  }
            }

        }


class TimerHolder : ObservableObject {
var timer : Timer!


   @Published var count = false

    init(){
        self.start()
    }

func start() {
    self.timer?.invalidate()
    self.count = false
    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 60, repeats: true) {
        _ in
        self.count = true
        print(self.count)
    }
}
}
```